# Statistics on Success / Fail Ratio of Ethereum Transactions

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

Is there any statistics on number of successful transactions comparing to number of sent transactions to the Ethereum main network?

In my own experience of sending bunch of transacitons (by Go), I could see that something like 20% of transactions which primarily is pending on Ethereum network will not become successful (same happens when I am using Ethereum wallet).

I want to know whether I should modify my code (e.g. gas price) or this successful ratio is something normal for the Ethereum transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple application using [etherscan api](https://etherscan.io/apis), but remember they have a limit for how many transactions you can do in a given span of time.

Comment: Indeed I have done that and I mentioned the 20% of fail rate by the etherscan API. I wanted to double check my experience with similar experiences